# Federal Funds Rate & Reserves Market Contradiction

Tags: interest-rate, monetary-policy, banking, central-banking, federal-reserve

**Edit**: I do understand this isn't how things work anymore, since we are in a "Ample-Reserves Framework" and the quantity of reserves no longer makes a difference that much and it is primarily IOR and ON RRP that has taken over as the Major Monetary Policy. But nonetheless, I was trying to understand through the point of view of pre 2008.

According to the Mishkin book “**Excess reserves are insurance against deposit outflows, and the cost of holding these excess reserves is their OPPORTUNITY COST—the interest rate that could have been earned on lending these reserves out…then as the federal funds rate decreases, the opportunity cost of holding excess reserves falls... and the Quantity of Reserves Demanded rises**”

I’m going to try and rephrase what he says in the way I understand it. Say I was a Bank, and I was ok with holding 100 million in excess reserves at a federal funds rate of 4%. That would mean I am ok with missing out on, assuming the Fed doesn’t pay interest on reserves, 100 * 0.04 = 4 million of interest payments (I know it’s not the correct number since loans are usually overnight and rates are annualized, but to keep it simple I went ahead with this.)

Now Imagine all of a sudden, the federal funds rate becomes 2.5%. That would mean me as a Bank would NOW be ok with holding $160 million because in the 2.5% scenario holding 160 mil in reserves costs me the same amount of Potential Money in Interest as 100 mil in the 4% scenario (100 * 0.04= X * 0.025, solve for X where X=160). The ADDED BENEFIT here is that I have even more buffering in terms of liquidity because I have an extra 60 million in reserves. But I’m not the only bank who thinks like this so every other bank would also prefer to hold more reserves for liquidity at a lower opportunity cost. On the other hand, the banks that are SHORT OF RESERVES would much prefer to borrow more money NOW because the **COSTS** are now much cheaper compared to the 4% scenario. Thus, keeping everything else the same, the overall “Quantity of Reserves Demanded” goes higher as Fed Fund rate drops both due to Banks wanting to hold on to Excess Reserves + Banks wanting to borrow cheaper reserves.

However, we also always hear that **as Interest Rates drop banks are willing to give out more loans**. But I’m having a hard time trying to reconcile this fact with that of as Fed Fund rate drops a bank wants to hold onto more reserves (hence, give out less loans). **So how does it make sense that as Fed Funds rate decreases banks prefer more excess reserves(which technically means giving out less loans) and also are willing to give out more loans? It's contradictory**

Thanks

[image]

Comment: This concept is completely out of date, now that the Fed pays a market rate of interest on reserves.

Comment: Yes. I do understand OMO no longer makes up the major monetary policy. Instead IOR and ON RRP have taken over as we are in a Ample-Reserves Framework. But I was still trying to understand the Pre-2008 way of things.

Comment: @dm63 You should read the post carefully, that is literally what the post says

Comment: @1muflon1 I added the edit after dm63 pointed it out. It wasn't there before.

Comment: Not sure I see a contradiction. Looking at your graph, Rs increases due to central bank action, Rd does not change but it's simply a move along the demand curve. Also, banks do not prefer to loan out more money if rates are low. It's just that demand for loans goes up naturally when it's cheaper (who would want, or can pay 15% vs 1% for a fixed rate loan for 10 years?).

Comment: @AKdemy I think I was looking at the problem wrong. I was thinking that in the 4% scenario as a bank I would, for example, start with 1 billion in excess reserves and loan out 900 mil at 4% which would give me 36 mil in interest and leave me with 100 mil excess. And in the 2.5% scenario I would loan out 840 mil at 2.5% which gives 21 mil in interest payments leaving me with 160 mil in excess reserves but that wouldn't make sense from a profit standpoint because I'm making way less profit in interest now. So I wouldn't start off with 1 billion in excess reserves in the 2.5% scenario.

Comment: I would have to start off with 1.6 billion in excess reserves and loan out up to 1.440 billion at 2.5% to make the same interest profit as 900 mil at 4% in which case I can understand how as federal funds rate drops banks do loan out more money.

Comment: I am a risk manager at a bank and no bank would compute it that way. Interest profit constantly changes and increased /decreases with changing interest rates. For example, the current upward trend in rates usually adds a lot of profit to the banking book.

Comment: @AKdemy That's actually good to know that you're a risk manager. I just assumed that since reserves are more plentiful in the 2.5% scenario banks wouldn't want to operate a significant decrease in interest profits relative to before and thus loan out more reserves to stay along the same profits. Then what you're actually saying is that banks actually don't like it when interest rates are low even though far more people are asking for loans which could offset the decrease in interest rates.

Comment: As I remember , in the old regime of scarce reserves , banks organized themselves to have as small as possible excess reserves , regardless of the interest rate.

Comment: @AKdemy Another question if you don't mind me asking. In the Demand Curve for Reserves in the graph above, when the fed funds rate decreases does that mean that the current value of the govt bond securities that banks are holding shoots up which in turn makes them want to sell it to the Fed in exchange for reserves hence resulting in the increase in Qty of Reserves Demanded ?

Comment: These charts are simple models. They try to explain the aggregate action of banks. However, I recommend not think too much about them, especially if you look at individual bank behavior. Back then, it was more  attractive for a bank to lend its excess liquidity in interbank markets (rather than depositing at a central Bank). As a bank you don't just decide about how many loans to offer. You also don't just knock on the door of the central bank & sell government bonds to it if prices go up. Overall, it's best not to waste time on these old models as the current system is completely different.

Comment: It's also not an increase in demand but just a movement along the same demand schedule if the FED changes supply to lower the rate.

Comment: @AKdemy I was just trying to understand where would these extra reserves actually come from in the movement along the same demand curve if the fed funds rate dropped? And the only place they can come from is the Fed itself if it starts buying up Govt Bonds from the Banks. And the only way I can logically explain it myself is that a decrease in fed funds rate would result in banks bonds becoming higher in present value hence them wanting to sell them for reserves and thus the total Qty of Reserves shifts along the demand curve.